# To what advantages can I override the model methods in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I know you can override the model methods but I was curious as to What all is possible is through this ?

Also another question if people want to answer ->

I wanted to design security checks, whenever anybody is updating and/or deleting from a model. Is it advisable to implement these somehow in the model methods or is it better to keep this logic in the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know you can override the model methods but I was curious as to What all is possible is through this ?

Sometimes you need it. What if you need to do something else other than db operation while saving and deleting?

For example, you have a model with ImageField/FileField. You'll want to override their save and delete (save the image/file to the disk when adding rows to the db, and delete them when deleting rows)

> I wanted to design security checks, whenever anybody is updating and/or deleting from a model. Is it advisable to implement these somehow in the model methods or is it better to keep this logic in the views?

I dont know about your security checks. However, it's common to define custom methods on your model for row level functionality, and on your Manager (django.db.models.Manager) for table functionality.

the process to get models added/updated/deleted = view code

the nitty gritty (internal) of adding/updating/deleting models = model or manager code

EDIT: formatting

Comment: Hey kusut, thanks for answering, so my basic problem is that -> while deleting a row I want to check if the person deleting ( request.user ) is the owner/creator ( field in the row ) of the entry .

Comment: IMO, override the save method. check the user before calling save

Comment: or maybe you block your entire view for wrong authentication. I dont know. this is your business process, you know it better than I do

Comment: I think you better do that in your view for deleting

Comment: on a second thought, I agree with @juankysmith